# MassTransit Job Consumer: cancel in-progress job?

Tags: c#, jobs, masstransit

I'm working on a project that uses MassTransit, but due to long-running work, has to use [Job Consumers](https://masstransit-project.com/advanced/job-consumers.html) to circumvent the timeout in RabbitMQ.

However, this brings with it the problem of cancelling these in-progress jobs. Through the RabbitMQ web interface we can purge queues to reset stalls in our pipelines, but this obviously doesn't work with job consumers.

My code does respect the `CancellationToken` that is passed with the `JobContext<...>` argument to the `IJobConsumer` but I don't know how to trigger it, and I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can cancel a job that is either running or waiting to be run by publishing the `CancelJob` command:

```cs
await x.Publish<CancelJob>(new { JobId = jobId });
```